# Multi-label classification with neural networks: Are correlations between class labels taken into account?

Tags: classification, correlation, neural-networks, multilabel

I am solving [multi-label classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification) problem (assigning each image 1 to N labels) and want to use neural network (like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164749/how-does-keras-handle-multilabel-classification/44165755) post). Does this approach take correlations between class labels into account? Or are the predictions for individual labels completely independent (like in the binary relevance approach)?

Comment: Please add details and context about your classification problem Multi-label classification is ambiguous: are you assigning one label to each sample, or possibly multiple ones? If it's the former, then a softmax is the way to go as everything would add up to 1. So classes would be correlated during training.

Comment: Multiple ones, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

For sure correlation is taken into account since your hidden layer mixing all signals from input together via fully connected layer. Your network will learn about co-occurrence of labels, however it's done in not-random way, I meant your network would find some deterministic rules for generating the best output. Be aware that this only 'projection' of statistical correlation into NN's linear space forced by your NN's optimization function.  You won't have any direct influence on that

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @podludek as long as you have a hidden layer your neural network should be able to learn label correlations.

There is also indeed a risk that your neural network learns deterministic rules of label co-occurence, by "assigning" some hidden units to some particular label sets. One way to alleviate this would be to use dropout, to force your neural network to learn general representations of your examples rather than making a deterministic encoding of some specific training data points.

You can for instance refer to [this paper](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1312.5419) investigating this label correlation with NNs on text data.

So in a nutshell: yes NNs can inherently capture some multilabel correlations. Still, there exist several methods to help them capture the correlations better, and as always in ML, there's no free lunch and you will have to try and check what works best for your setting.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that paper! Dropout seems to be de rigueur for any neural network anyway, regardless of whether the problem is multi-label classification or regression. Though additionally here there's risk of overfitting to specific subsets of labels, as mentioned.

Comment: Although I'd be interested to know how the degree of correlations in different datasets might have affected the results, since the binary relevance approach seemed to be competitive for some datasets. I also wonder why rank loss is the "most intuitive" objective for multi-label learning, vs say average precision?

Comment: I guess the "most intuitive" statement is quite subjective and stems from an information retrieval (recommender systems) origin of document classification. From an information retrieval perspective you don't care about interpreting scores as probabilities and a perfect recommender system is simply the one ranking higher the relevant documents/labels. While the average precision does require you to interpret your output scores as probabilities, and will depend on your score distribution (you could construct many classifiers with the same ranking but different AP)

Comment: As for the degree of correlation for sure it plays a role. One side note on BR being competitive: you also have to take into account the fact that BR requires to learn a different NN model for each label, and the same goes for inference. This makes quite an overhead and should be taken into account when assessing "competitivity"